# Decode my Girlfriend's Message

Tags: cipher

My girlfriend left me this message. Help me decode it:

**H-s-He, He-s-He, He-p-C, Li-s-He, Li-p-C, Li-d-Ne, Be-s-He, Be-p-C, Be-d-Ne, B-s-He, B-p-B //  H-s-He, He-s-He, He-p-C, Li-s-He, Li-p-C, Li-d-Ne, Be-s-He, Be-p-C, Be-d-Ne, Be-f-Si, B-s-He, B-p-C, B-d-H C-s-He // H-s-He, He-s-He, He-p-C, Li-s-He, Li-p-C, Li-d-Ne, Be-s-He // H-s-He, He-s-He, He-p-C, Li-s-He, Li-p-C, Li-d-Ne, Be-s-He, Be-p-C, Be-d-Ne, Be-f-Si, B-s-He, B-p-C, B-d-Ne, B-si-Li, C-s-He, C-p-C, C-d-H, N-s-He**

Comment: Are you missing a comma in between B-d-H and C-s-He? Also, should "B-si-Li" be "B-s-Li"?

Comment: Damn, I'll never understand girls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the same logic, if you:

> replace numbers to get electronic configurations,

We get the elements

> Iodine, Lutetium, Zinc (could be Vanadium - error somewhere) and Uranium. I, Lu, Zn (maybe V), U; to spell "I Luv U". I suppose you were declaring your love to your girlfriend?

Comment: It could be V or Zn, due to stable electron configuration, but for this situation the V would make more sense. You know they answer but you never fully wrote the decoded answer so I still can't give you check mark yet

Comment: @Krishna its message from girlfriend not from him:P

Comment: Good job you got the right answer

Answer (score 1):

If we

> replace the chemical symbols by their atomic numbers

we get

> [electron configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration) for the elements I, La, Zn, Ac. (I'm not sure what exactly this is supposed to mean, but it *almost* spells out a coherent message ("I laz[y] ????") if you squint.)

Comment: Close, but remember metals tend to have variations in their electron configuration, so the elements are wrong. Find the most common usage of the element